# Do I have to declare columns in my datatable before setting datagridview datasource?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I already have the columns added in my datagridview, but I need to load the rows faster, and the way I have done that now is to use a datatable, but it forces me to declare the columns in order to add the rows to the table, but is there a way not to declare them, as they are already added to the datagridview, and I don't want same columns 2 times..

This is the code:

```
        Using reader As New StringReader(Clipboard.GetText())
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        While reader.Peek() <> -1
            Dim cp_text As String = reader.ReadLine()
            cp_text = cp_text.Replace(" ", "")
            If Not cp_text = "" Then
                dt.Rows.Add(cp_text, "", "", "", "", True)
                'addinternallink(cp_text, "")
            End If
        End While
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
    Label3.Text = "Total: " & DataGridView1.RowCount
```

Anyway, the thing I am trying to achieve is just to add rows the quickest way possible.

Comment: The DGV can/will autogenerate columns based on the datatable.  Any performance issues are more likely related to that one line at a time string read/chop/replace code

Comment: In your code you have not defined the column names and types. When you try to add a row at this table you should get an exception. So, yes you need to define column in the DataTable, however you don't need to define them in the DataGridView when AutoGenerateColumn is true because the grid will get the column names from the datasource

Comment: Getting your string from the Clipboard seems a pretty unreliable way to do things.  I would rethink that strategy.

Comment: @Steve - Indeed, I am getting an exception, that the row could not be added since the columns does not exist in the table (something like that).

Comment: @Plutonix - The performance is actually fine when I use the datatable, the problem is just that I MUST define columns in the datatable, and as I already have added them to the datagridview, it adds the same columns again, and I don't need that, as this is a import function.

Comment: In the grid, just set the DataPropertyName property for each column that matches the column name in your DataTable.

Comment: I guess I will just define a datatable for each datagridview when the form loads.

Comment: However, I would try to measure the performances without using the DataTable but instead adding directly the rows to your grid. If you think about it you are looping two times on the data. The first one is your code when you add  data to the DataTable, the second one is the code inside the binding process of the grid. It reads your table another time to add rows to the grid.

Comment: @Steve - It will be much slower if it adds a new row to the dgv for each line.

Comment: You dont show any code related to the issue of adding any columns to any thing.  Most of what you are describing need not be the case - you could add more rows to the *same* datatable - or even a collection - and not have to redo anything.  You should read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn what to do in regards to those answers on your previous posts.

Comment: @LarsTech - Can you give an example of how I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you updated your post with more code.  I gave you a property name, so that should have been fairly simple to google.  `dgv.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Column1";`

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech